# Integração Netbeans + Php7.0 + Apache2 + Debian : melhores práticas

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, linux

Estava com problemas para habiltar o apache2 para executar páginas .php.

Aí fiz o seguinte:

Removi do endereço Directory a pasta html, ficou assim o arquivo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Removi a pasta html em /var/www/html porque o NetBeans ao tentar criar um projeto em .php ele não deixava gravar na pasta www porque não estava vazia.

Mudei a permissão da pasta /var/www para chmod 777

Alterei o arquivo /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf , removendo  o html do endereço /var/www

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora todo projeto que crio roda corretamente no endereço localhost/index.php.
Antes disso recebi a mensagem que o arquivo index.php não existia naquele servidor:

*Not Found*

The requested URL /html/index.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80

Além dos mais, quando existia a pasta html e ela estava corretamente configurada nos arquivos 000-default.conf e apache2.conf com o index.php dentro dela, não funcionava, aparecia a mesma mensagem not found, mas se eu removesse html do endereço localhost/html/index.php, a página rodava normalmente. Não consegui entender até agora o porquê disso.

Alguma coisa me diz que essa não é a maneira correta de organizar as coisas. Alguém poderia dar sua contribuição sobre  **melhores práticas**  nesse caso? Como devo configurar corretamente o apache2, php7.0 mais NetBeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é recomendado modificar o arquivo 000-defult.conf, Se trabalha com desenvolvimento e a aplicação não ter a necessidade de ser acessada pela rede, o correto seria utilizar as instalações independentes do php e do mysql, assim não seria necessário instalar o apache uma vez que através do terminal do netbeans você poderia criar uma porta virtual para testar a aplicação, o recomendado seria instalar o apache para testar servidores ou até implementar aplicações em uma rede local.

> NetBeans

1. Com o NetBeans aberto abra o projeto, em seguida abra o arquivo de index do mesmo.
2. Agora vai na barra de **ferramentas** e clique em **Abrir no terminal**
3. Na parte inferior verá que o terminal estará aberto, e já estará dentro do diretório.
4. Agora faça login do root no terminal, da mesma forma que faz para instalar pacotes `sudo su`
5. Agora basta criar o servidor virtual do php usando o seguinte comando

   `php -S localhost:8080`

Agora basta ir no navegador e digitar http://localhost:8080 e já estará acessando o projeto via browser, lembrando que a porta 8080 eu utilizei por escolha própria mas pode ser qualquer uma desde que não esteja sendo utilizada por outro processo.

A vantagem de utilizar o terminal dentro do netbeans é a praticidade de instalar pacotes e gerencial conteúdo como `NODE`, `BOWER`, `GULP`, ETC...

Esta a forma que venho trabalhando e compartilhando com colegas, mas existem diversas outras formas.